# does logarithmic depth buffer method properly interpolate vertex attribute?

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer, depth

I read about the logarithmic depth buffer. does it interpolate vertex attributes properly?
I thought the rendering pipeline goes down this way.

vertex shader -> divide by w -> viewport transform -> interpolation -> fragment shader

```
(Zclip)  ---------------- (Zndc)  ---------    (Zwindow)
```

When interpolation happens, rasterizer does linear interpolation about Zwindow.
Because Zwindow is proportional to 1/Zview, we come to apply perspective interpolation about Zview
with linear interpolation about Zwindow.

But, in the logarithmic depth buffer, they manipulate z value in vertex shader. 
It means that Zwindow values are no more proportional to 1/Zview
and rasterizer's interpolation is no more correct.

Do I understand correctly? what am I missing here?

Comment: Nowadays floating point depth buffers make the logarithmic hack obsolete. Just go with a floating point buffer. Disabling depth clamp and setting `GL_ZERO_TO_ONE` lets you use the entire floating point precision over the entire depth range from zero to infinity.

Comment: @ybungalobill ok, I will try.

Answer (score 1):

> do I  understand correctly?

Yes.

> what am I missing here?

That for a properly working logarithmic depth buffer, one has to apply the logarithm per fragment, in the fragment shader.

There are a couple of ways to approach this:

1. You do not use the logarithm in the vertex shader, so that the linear interpolation is correct, and just apply the logarithmic distortion at the fragment shader. This approach is of course quite silly, because the precision will be limited to what a floating point depth buffer would give you anyway, and since most of the fragments will fall into the `[0.5,1]` interval in window space, you basically have a fixed precision using only a single exponent, and going the logarithmic space after that won't gain you much.
2. You try to "fix" the wrongly interpolated values at the fragment shader, as [this article](https://www.gamedev.net/blog/73/entry-2006307-tip-of-the-day-logarithmic-zbuffer-artifacts-fix/) describes in detail.
3. You do variant 1, just in a not-so-silly way. The precision loss is basically occurring at the perspective divide when going from clip space to NDC (and again when going to window space). You can simply pass the *eye space* z value on to the fragment shader (properly interpolated in a perspective-correct manner automatically for you by the GPU), and just apply the logarithm on *that* in the fragment shader.

Note that logarithmic depth buffer is not a so good idea anyway, since it requires you modify the depth for each fragment, so you lose the early depth test and all performance benefits that come from that. There are alternatives like [reversed Z](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/depth-precision-visualized) which will not have such drawbacks.

Comment: even though I do something to my fragment shader, I think  interpolation is still wrong , because, interpolation is done "before fragment shader". that is my core question.

Comment: @society73 I updated my answer to make more clear what I meant by "apply the logarithm per fragment"